# How use multiple Instances of same HSM in QP/C?

Tags: state-machine

I'm using QP/C Framework from http://state-machine.com with an ARM Cortex-M0 CPU.

Can someone provide some help/guidance on how use a simple HSM with multiple instances in QP/C Framework?

I've build a HSM (Hierarchical State Machine) to manage a physical button press/hold behavior in a custom PCB board I'm developing.
The board has four buttons. So I need four instances of the HSM, one for each button.

I've designed the HSM as an QActive object and tested it to one button, and worked perfectly.

Now I need to adjust it to accept all buttons but I don't know how to transform my QActive object to four instances.

This image shows the State Machine diagram:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably already have some code that looks like this:

```
typedef struct MyActiveObjectTag {
    QActive super;
    ...
} MyActiveObject;

...

static MyActiveObject l_myactiveobject;   /* Declare an instance */

...

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    ...
    /* instantiate and start the active objects... */
    MyActiveObject_ctor(&l_myactiveobject);
    QACTIVE_START(&l_myactiveobject, ...
    ...
}
```

So I believe you just want to repeat the declaration line to declare `l_myactiveobject1`, `2`, `3`, and `4` for example.  And then in `main` call the constructor and `QACTIVE_START` for each instance.  It seems like you probably need a member variable in `MyActiveObject` that associates each instance with the proper button (a GPIO pin, I assume).  And you'll want to assign the value of that member variable in the constructor.

By the way, this level of abstraction seems pretty low (i.e., Pressed and NotPressed states for each of four buttons).  I wonder whether it would make sense to raise the level of abstraction so that your states represent what the application should be doing in response to those buttons.  Then you would just have events for button-press and button-release.  The button press events could have associated data that identifies which of the four buttons was pressed or released.

Comment: I've done as you suggested and it worked. I have created several instances with QACTIVE_START and added a member variable to identify each of them. The button state machine is a lower level state machine that send signals to others state machines, its not the main piece of working code of my application.